# I am writing an expect script where I have to need to pass multiple send command for an expect

Tags: expect

I am writing an expect script where I have to need to pass multiple send command for an expect.Because I am expecting "OK" for all the send command.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
{

set timeout 5

spawn ssh .......

expect "OK"

send "set connections 10\r"

send "INCR connections\r"

send "INCR connections\r"

send "INCR connections\r"

expect eof

}
```

This throws following error

```
invalid command name "
set timeout 5

spawn .......
expect "OK"
send "set connections 10\r"

send "INCR connections\r"


expect eof
"
    while executing
"{
set timeout 5
```

Answer (score 0):

May look silly but since `Set timeout` is the first line of code and its errorred..,please check where your Expect program actually residing on your system under /usr/bin/
Not all have their expect under /usr/bin/expect

some may have chances to have it in /usr/local/bin/expect or anywhere

may be if you posted program fully , check your shebang line, it should start with #

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the curly braces.  Just remove them.